# What to do when the induction removes too much information to make the goal solvable?

Tags: coq

```
Inductive subseq : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
  | subseq_base : subseq [] []
  | subseq_there : forall seq l x, subseq seq l -> subseq seq (x :: l)
  | subseq_here : forall seq l x, subseq seq l -> subseq (x :: seq) (x :: l).
```

```
Theorem subseq_snd :
  forall l1 l2 l,
  subseq (l1 ++ l2) l -> subseq l1 l.
Proof.
intros.
induction H.
-
```

```
1 subgoal
l1, l2 : list nat
______________________________________(1/1)
subseq l1 [ ]
```

Basically, Coq cannot recognize that `l1 ++ l2 = []` in this case also means that `l1 = []`, but because there are no premises, I cannot prove this either. What should be done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform induction on both `l1` and `l`, and use `H` to eliminate the impossible cases. Basically, I don't think you can directly perform induction on `H`; you have to do induction on the values it relates and tear `H` down while you go through them.

This lemma here should be defined first though. You *could* inline it in the proof, but its type is interesting enough to stand alone:

```
Theorem subseq_nil (l : list nat): subseq nil l.
Proof.
  induction l; constructor; assumption.
Qed.
```

And then the main proof:

```
Theorem subseq_snd (l1 l2 l : list nat): subseq (l1 ++ l2) l -> subseq l1 l.
Proof.
  (* I like to give parameters on the left side of the :, so I use revert to get the
     correct goal for the induction:
     forall l, subseq (l1 ++ l2) l -> subseq l1 l *)
  revert l; induction l1 as [ | x l1 Hl1]; intro l. (* It's best to give names *)
  - intros ?.
    apply subseq_nil.
  (* Below we get H : subseq (x :: foo) bar. The inversion tactic is like destruct
     but it spews out equalities about the type indices instead of leaving you stranded
     like induction would. In the l=nil case, inversion produces a contradiction,
     because subseq_nil has been ruled out, and, in the l=cons case, it case splits
     between subseq_there and subseq_here. *)
  - induction l as [ | x' l Hl]; simpl; intro H; inversion H.
    + apply subseq_there.
      apply Hl.
      assumption.
    + apply subseq_here.
      apply Hl1.
      assumption.
Qed.
```

Comment: Brilliant. I do not think I would've thought to try nested induction followed by an inversion. I've been trying to avoid nesting induction in the same proof due to its unpredictable behavior. The way I've tried going about this is to `remember (l1 ++ l2).` This gets me through the `subseq_base` and the `subseq_there` case, but Coq is still missing information it needs in the last one. I've tried making the proof I've envisioned in Idris, but is cannot do what I wanted there either. So this is a limitation on the logic capabilities of these languages.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic The proof is feasible using `remember`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I could not leave this question with no answer using `remember`. The proof looks very much like the one provided by @HTNW, but does not use `dependent induction` nor performs nested induction.

```
Theorem subseq_snd :
  forall l1 l2 l,
  subseq (l1 ++ l2) l -> subseq l1 l.
Proof.
  intros. remember (l1++l2) as L.
  revert l1 l2 HeqL.
  induction H; intros.
  - destruct l1.
    + apply subseq_base.
    + discriminate.
  - apply subseq_there. eapply IHsubseq, HeqL.
  - destruct l1.
    + apply subseq_nil.
    + inversion HeqL; subst. apply subseq_here.
      eapply IHsubseq; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the experimental tactic `dependent induction`. This is probably the closest to what you want. You'll need this lemma:

```
Theorem subseq_nil (l : list nat): subseq nil l.
Proof.
  induction l; constructor; assumption.
Qed.
```

Compared to double `induction` + `inversion`, this is a lot easier to read, even if it's longer. It has 3 `-` bullets, one per constructor, with only one recursive entry point. Indeed, I didn't even realize that `subseq` represented discontinuous subsequences until I used `dependent induction`, which made the structure of the program clear enough for me to realize what was happening. Also, the produced program term is a lot smaller.

```
Theorem subseq_app (l1 l2 l : list nat): subseq (l1 ++ l2) l -> subseq l1 l.
Proof.
  intro H.
  dependent induction H.
  - destruct l1.
    + constructor.
    + discriminate.
  - apply subseq_there.
    exact (IHsubseq _ _ eq_refl).
  - destruct l1.
    + apply subseq_nil.
    + injection x as [] prf_seq.
      apply subseq_here.
      exact (IHsubseq _ _ prf_seq).
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the idea of destructuring the lists, here is a version of the proof done in Idris for completeness. It turns out that Idris gets too cramped unless I destructure the implicit arguments.

```
data Subseq : List a -> List a -> Type where
    Base : Subseq [] []
    There : Subseq seq l -> Subseq seq (x :: l)
    Here : Subseq seq l -> Subseq (x :: seq) (x :: l)

subseq_empty : Subseq [] l
subseq_empty {l = []} = Base
subseq_empty {l = (x :: xs)} = There subseq_empty

subseq_snd : Subseq (l1 ++ l2) l -> Subseq l1 l
subseq_snd {l1 = []} {l} _ = subseq_empty
subseq_snd {l1 = (x :: xs)} {l = (y :: ys)} (There z) = There (subseq_snd z)
subseq_snd {l1 = (x :: xs)} {l = (x :: ys)} (Here z) = Here (subseq_snd z)
```

Apart from the destructured implicit arguments this is how imagined the proof should go.

Though the Little Typer praised Coq style tactics towards the end, as is apparent from the above there is definitely an argument for doing it like Idris does.